# In Apple's automator, how to pass files to another application?

Tags: automator

I am trying to create an automator application which does this:

1/ run the follwing command on all the files dragged to this workflow:
xargs -I{} exiftool -IPTC:Keywords= -XMP:Subject= {} −overwrite_original

2/ send all the files to another application (ImageOptim.app) afterwards.

Step 1 works flawlessly. I have no idea how to send the files to another application once step 1 is through. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The output for Automator's "Run Shell Script" action is text. You may want to look at something like [This](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus)